# Show splash screen at every launch

Tags: ipad, screen, splash-screen

My app uses a splash screen as per client requirement. I need to display this splash screen at every launch when user presses the home button again. Pressing app I need to load app from beginning or else display splash at a specific time interval.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the Multitasking capability of the app and make it start from scratch each time you re-open the app from the home screen.

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
      exit(0);
}

@end
```

OR See "[Opting Out of Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1)" in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1):

> "...you can explicitly opt out of the
>   background execution model by adding
>   the **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** key to
>   your application’s **Info.plist** file and
>   setting its value to **YES**."

Comment: Ya Thanks White, its working fine every time it launch from beginning. is there any solution for launching app where i stopped or closed i need go to that page directly